# How to play audio and video file together in SIPp

Tags: sip

Can SIPp support play audio and video file together in a call? Thanks.
I am able to initiate a sip audio call. What I want to achieve is, after the callee picks the call, play a audio and video file together.
I want to achieve this using the command line arguments. Has someone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it the same way you are playing a pre-recorded audio file. Please see the relevant section in the SIPp document:

```
PCAP (media) commands

PCAP play commands (specified using play_pcap_audio / play_pcap_video attributes) allow you to send a pre-recorded RTP stream using the pcap library.
Choose play_pcap_audio to send the pre-recorded RTP stream using the "m=audio" SIP/SDP line port as a base for the replay.
Choose play_pcap_video to send the pre-recorded RTP stream using the "m=video" SIP/SDP line port as a base.

The play_pcap_audio/video command has the following format: play_pcap_audio="[file_to_play]" with:
```